# How to fix "Invalid hook call" during a simple React MUI Component Library creation?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to build a public repository in which I will export a couple of React components build in `typescript`.

I added storybook and ts config fine. I can develop in storybook but the problem I face happens when I import the compiled/build package and use this component.
I get the following error:

[image]

I don't use any react hook directly in the component. I just use the mui/lab TextField for testing.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Clone my repository at https://github.com/kristijorgji/react-mui-components
2. run `yarn build` to compile into the relative `lib` folder
3. Use the generated library into one empty react project.
   You can add the local library like this

```
yarn add react-mui-components@file:/yourpath/react-mui-components
```

Then have a component like I did in your `client project`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { Button, Scheduler } from 'react-mui-components';

const ClientTest: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Button label={'kristi'} primary={false} />
            <Scheduler />
        </>
    );
};
export default ClientTest;
```

The above will end up in error that I showed.
I also use react mui wrapper in the client project App.tsx and inside it render the above ClientTest

If I render only `<Button label={'kristi'} primary={false} />` it works fine. The problem is with Scheduler component that is using react-mui TextField

I also specified in peerDependencies to use same react version as in my client project for

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.113",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1"
  }
```

I am using same versions in the client `dependencies` section

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this myself.
The problem was that react was included 2 times in the build via webpack (somehow).
One time included via node_modules folder of the client project and one time via node_modules of the library.

To fix that, I had to `npm link` react and react-dom of the library to the one of the client

```
clientProjectPathNodeModules=somepath/node_modules
npm link "$clientProjectPathNodeModules"/react
npm link "$clientProjectPathNodeModules"/react-dom
```

Afterward all worked smooth without the error.

PS: I Added the fix script in my public repository as well + the instructions on the README.md